# Unicode strings on a embedded software

Tags: c++

I need to write an app on embedded device using C++.
I may need to support Unicode too (though I am not an expert on it). I had
a look at Joel Spoolsky's article too about Unicode: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

My question is given what I mentioned above, what is the way to go with Unicode
in such a application in C++? Should I use wchar_t everywhere? or std::wstring?

What problems I may encounter in using wchar_t all the time? (this post mentions some problems one might encounter with unicode strings: [Switching from std::string to std::wstring for embedded applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163962/switching-from-stdstring-to-stdwstring-for-embedded-applications) - but I am still kind of confused as to don't know what to do exactly).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Comment: @dalle: I consider both the linked question and its "accepted" answer to be severely misguided. None of the problems mentioned are inherent to UTF-16, they are inherent to multibyte encodings and applications written in ignorance of multibyte implications. Using UTF-8 instead doesn't really solve the problems, and using UTF-32 still doesn't solve the issue of e.g. combining characters. You want to go beyond ISO-8859, you have to *understand* Unicode, multibyte, *and* the limits of wide characters. No way around it.

Comment: What do you need to *do* with your Unicode strings? Once you start looking at individual characters, things get tricky and you'll need a library with robust Unicode support to do all your string manipulation, but if you just need to store (and maybe concatenate) valid Unicode strings, then you should be fairly safe.

Comment: @jalf: "What do you need to do with your Unicode strings?"
--> yes, this I am not sure exactly yet what I need to do with them though.

Comment: @DevSolar: I just wanted to point out that `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` aren't needed to *support* Unicode. I'm sure that using UTF-8 (instead of UTF-16) will on the other hand force developers to think of Code Units much earlier, and not lead them into thinking that a `wchar_t` is a Character or a Code Point. I'm sure of this because it is very likely that they encounter non-ASCII characters far more often than non-BMP characters. And I'm hoping that using UTF-8 will in turn make the developer to think even further of the complexity of Unicode.

Comment: @dalle: Correct, `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` are not needed - they are woefully inadequate. "Support" is more than just storing data: Conversion, collation, searching...

Answer (score 6):

"Supporting" Unicode goes *well* beyond using `wchar_t` or `std::wstring` (which are merely "types suitable for some wide-character encoding which might or might not be actually Unicode depending on current locale and platform").

Think things like `isalpha()`, tokenizing, coverting to / from different encodings etc., and you get the idea.

Unless you *know* you can get away with build-in stuff like `wchar_t` / `std::wstring` (and you wouldn't ask in that case), you are better off using the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library, which is the state-of-the-art implementation for Unicode *support*. (Even the otherwise-recommendable Boost.Locale relies on ICU to provide the actual logic.)

The C way of doing Unicode in ICU are arrays of type `UChar []` (UTF-16), the C++ way is the class `icu::UnicodeString`. I happen to work with a legacy codebase that goes great lengths to "make do" with `UChar []` for claims of performance (shared references, memory pooling, copy-on-write etc.), but still fails to outperform `icu::UnicodeString`, so you might feel safe in using the latter even in an embedded environment. They did a good job there.

**Post scriptum:** Take note that `wchar_t` is of implementation-defined length; 32bit on the Unixes I know of, and 16bit on Windows - which gives additional trouble since `wchar_t` should be "wide", but UTF-16 is still "multibyte" when it comes to Unicode. If you can rely on the environment supporting C++11, `char16_t` resp. `char32_t` would be better choices, yet still agnostic of finer print like combining characters.

Comment: "performance ... Copy On Write". It turns out COW is _not_ good for performance on modern systems. The savings just don't justify the costs.

Comment: @MSalters: Not to mention the amount of custom code, complete with memory leaks, lack of suitable documentation etc. -- ignoring existing implementations because you think you can do better "rolling your own" is a recipee for desaster 9 times out of 10. Funny I never came across the 10th time yet in all those years. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You've read Joel's article, but it seems you have not understood it.  std::wstring or strings of wchar_t are not Unicode, they are wide character strings that may contain UCS-2 or UTF-16 Unicode strings, or something else.  std::string may contain plain ASCII, or ANSI w. codepage strings, or they may contain UTF-8 Unicode strings, or something else.

Both of these occur often: the std::wstring tends to be UTF-16 on Windows, std::string tends to be UTF-8 on POSIX.

DevSolar's advice is sound - have a look at ICU instead, it'll save you from an awful lot of headache and misunderstanding.